# How can I remove 'build' in application - edit configuration in intelliJ permanently?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I try to run a single class, it runs every classes in the project, even when I specifically clicked a single class. I found the solution to this is to go to Edit Configuration -> remove 'build' in 'Before Launch' tap. I removed it in Default -> Application tap as well.

However, every time I reopen IntelliJ, the configuration seems to have reset, and 'build' is back.

I can't understand why I am the only one who has this problem. I think it should be annoying for everyone if I need to remove something from configurations to run a single class every time I use Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the "Defaults", every launcher is starts from "Defaults" configuration.

(But I still recommend you keep the "Build" as the java file will be changed and you do not need to compile it before launch it.)

Comment: Thanks. I did in the Defaults, and it keeps coming back, and that's the problem I am having, though!